# Pandas .iloc[] not working with index range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` as below:

```
                     Name               Count
[{‘text’: ‘Server1.com’}]       [{‘text’: 1}]
[{‘text’: ‘Server3.com’}]       [{‘text’: 1}]
[{‘text’: ‘Server2.com’}]      [{‘text’: 22}]
```

I want to transform this into:

```
           Name      Count
    Server1.com          1        
    Server3.com          1
    Server2.com         22
```

What I am trying is this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
   df1 = pd.concat([df1, df[i].iloc[0:][0][‘text’]], axis=1)
```

But it gives me `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

When I checked, `df[0].iloc[0][0][‘text’]` it rightly transforms the element of `row1,column1`

Does `iloc` Not work with slices `[0:]` ? Is there a simpler way to do it ?

Please note, my dataframe would not always have fixed number of rows or columns - 3 and 2 respectively - as shown in my example above. But each field would always have values in the form of `[{‘text’: value}]` i.e list of length 1, and the element is always a dictionary with key as ‘text’

Comment: Do you also construct the data frame? Because it could be easier to fix this prior to making the data frame.

Comment: Yes I construct the dataframe df from a nested dictionary out of a json response from an API, and just keep the needed data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy option is to use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
out = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0]['text'])
```

Another option:

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s.str[0].str['text'])
```

Output:

```
          Name  Count
0  Server1.com      1
1  Server3.com      1
2  Server2.com     22
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [[{'text': 'Server1.com'}],
                            [{'text': 'Server3.com'}],
                            [{'text': 'Server2.com'}]],
                   'Count': [[{'text': 1}],
                             [{'text': 1}],
                             [{'text': 22}]]
                   })
```